# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 543, 428, 3)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, image-classification

Following is my code.

My train_images are of `size(543,428,3)`. I m not able to fix this error. Can someone suggest about image reshaping in case of LSTM.

```
model_rnn = Sequential([
    LSTM(units= 64, activation= 'tanh', input_shape= [543,428], return_sequences = True),
    Dropout(0.25),
    LSTM(units= 128, activation= 'tanh', return_sequences = True),
    Dropout(0.3),
    LSTM(units= 128, activation= 'tanh', return_sequences = True),
    Dropout(0.35),
    LSTM(units= 256, activation= 'tanh', return_sequences = True),
    Flatten(),

    Dense(256, activation= 'relu'),
    Dropout(0.25),
    Dense(128, activation= 'relu'),
    Dropout(0.35),
    Dense(64, activation= 'relu'),
    Dense(2, activation= 'softmax'),

  ])
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: As the error message states, your model receives inputs of shape `(batch, 543, 428, 3)`, but LSTMs expect only 3 input dims, namely `(batch, time, features)`
You can theoretically resolve this issue by reshaping your data into this format, but I don't get what you are trying to do: LSTMs are used for time-series/sequential data, but you only have single images as the input, right?

Comment: No i have 2 class dataset and i want to classify it using LSTM model. My dataset has class 1 with 90 images and class 2 with 90 images.

Comment: What I mean is that LSTMs exploit temporal dependencies, but classifying one image does not contain any information about what class the next image will be. This is then a standard image classification and in this case, LSTM is the wrong choice of layer here and you should use Conv2D for this task.
Why do you want to use LSTM?

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can i use CNN+LSTM for classification?

Comment: This would make sense if you had Videos, but not so much for individual images.
Is there a reason you want to use LSTM?

Comment: I want to make analyze the classification results of standard CNN and LSTM.

Comment: Those two operations are used for fundamentally different things - Conv2D are applied to images and LSTM are applied to time series. Comparing the performance of both on an image dataset makes no sense. Its as if you would compare a bike with a ladder - the bike is for moving forward and the ladder for climbing. If that makes sense^^

Comment: A setting that would make more sense is to get sequential data and apply Conv2D/Conv1D and LSTM to sequential data